# About Mac Code Signing, notarization ,disk images and Python

Tags: python, macos, qt, code-signing

I've several doubts about the new Mac Mojave requirements and for future OS support.
Let's say I make a Mac APP with QT that also supports an embedded Python interpreter, so in the end I sign it using a valid Certificate, signing the main app, all the QT frameworks, all the QT plugins and also all the Python Stuff.
I package everything into a DMG and I sign the DMG too, and we also send the DMG for notarization to Apple doing all the great things in the good way.
When my end user install my App , everything goes well but what about if they want to extend the Python interpreter with their own Python dylib plugin ? Is this kind of customization lost forever ?????

Thanks to anyone that would like to discuss the topic....

Comment: Maybe i used "discuss" wrong, but this is a real coding problem from my point of view and would need a solution....

Comment: It's really not clear exactly what you're asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I'm asking how to let signed code dynamic load unsigned code, if this is possible or not....considering it's a relative new topic I've write a question that sounds like a discussion but that wasn't the intention...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  This type of customization by end users is sadly indistinguishable from the same kind of "customization" that malware would want to do to your app to acquire access to its data.

You can, however, enable users to still (securely) access your application with code they write themselves via https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsapplescript?language=objc# and similar automation tools.

Comment: There are several high end applications like autodesk maya that lives on those customization .. a dlopen from a signed app will be able to open a dylib signed by another developer ?

Comment: Apple script is a toy , this is not an option for cross platform applications that must share the same workflow across all the platforms

Comment: Arguing with me won’t do any good, I don’t work for apple and can’t affect their policies any more than you can :-).

Comment: You can watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/702/ for more info on the upcoming changes.

Comment: To your point about Maya though, Autodesk has several options: 1. Be autodesk. Apple might add legacy carve outs for existing popular applications for a long time. 2. Come up with a system where they have other developers submit their plugins to autodesk instead of signing them themselves, so that the signing identifiers match. 3 — and I strongly suspect that, long term, this is where Apple is pushing everyone — rebuild their plugin architecture to use inter-process communication of some kind (apple events, XPC), so it is inherently more secure/securable.

Comment: Finally, regarding your question about dlopen and signing identifiers: see “using library validation” in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html .